# Missing Ubuntu When format windows again

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop. I used both OS more than 1 year. Attacked my window OS by harmful virus. After that I format the Windows partition (C:/) then boot Windows 10 again. Now my Ubuntu partition is missing. When I check with windows disk manager My Ubuntu partition shows as free space(Not unallocated). I try Ubuntu again with CD. but the Partition not showing there. I didn't backup my Ubuntu partition before this. How can I get data from my Ubuntu partition and Dual boot both again? Please help me.

Edit: Screenshot of Gparted from comment

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: Not clear your comment. please can you explain? without DVD mean?

Comment: You have to boot Ubuntu from a live USB DVD or CD. Use the "try Ubuntu without installing" option. Then open the program called gparted from within Ubuntu. Use ALT+PrintScrn buttons to take a screenshot of gparted.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxIAeQorrgfuQXVEZTVFd2VOZ3c       This is the screen shot of gparted

Comment: Try Boot-Repair-Disk:   https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/   Select 32bit or 64bit according to your PC, or it will not work.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Ubuntu installation was completely erased when you installed Windows 10.

You have to install Ubuntu again. Ubuntu should find the unallocated 72.63 GB space in the extended partition /dev/sda4 when you select the option of installing Ubuntu side by side Windows 10. If it does not, then use the option **something else** and then manually select the **unallocated** space. Set it to format as ext4 and select mountpoint `/`.

You may or may not need a separate partition for Swap partition. If you do, you will need to make that out of that unallocated space as well.

Hope this helps